How can we find the angle between areal vector and magnetic field?

For finding torque we need to find the angle between areal vector and magnetic field. But areal vector makes an angle 37° with the x axis and that means it makes 53° with magnetic field because that's along y axis. So in the the formula we'll substitute 53° right? But why is 37°?

How did you get $53$ degrees? You should probably draw the geometry from above so you can see how exactly it is $37$ degrees.
